# Create separate test module/project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm using Android Studio version 0.8.14. Currently, after creating a new Android project, by default the test source code folder `androidTest` is located inside the `src` folder of the `app` module, at the same level as `main` (which contains application source code).
But if, for any particular reason, I want to move the test code into a separate module in my project, or even further, into a separate project other than the project I'm using for application source code, can I do this?

To make it easier for you to understand what I'm asking, a 'picture' would be better. The current default new project structure which Android Studio create is something looks like this:

```
My Project
    |___my app module
        |___src
            |___androidTest
            |___main
```

Now I want something looks like this:

```
My Project
    |___my app module
    |    |___src
    |        |___main
    |___my test module
```

or this:

```
My App Project
|    |___my app module
|
My Test Project (some how linked to My App Project)
```

How can I get this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking, the bit of information that you might be missing is to add something like:

```
include ':my app module', ':my test module'
```

to your settings.gradle file.  I use this technique to separate out my 'connected' tests from pure unit tests.  You might be interested in checking out a fork that I made of the popular deckard-gradle project that does exactly this:  https://github.com/jdonmoyer/deckard-gradle

Answer (score 1):

The technique for specifying a test directory other than "androidTest" is to add a "sourceSets" configuration option to the "build.gradle" file as shown below:

```
 sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
 }
```

The above example would only change the name of the test directory from "androidTest" to "test".

But you could try the same technique using a relative or full path name such as

```
setRoot('../my test module/my app module/src/androidTest')
```

or

```
setRoot('../../My Test Project/src/androidTest')
```